# Numba : Why guvectorize is so slow?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numba

I am learning numba to try to optimize my code.
First, I calculated *a*exp(b*x)* where a and b are two parameters and x a large numpy array. I used the `@jit` decorator. The output is 1D array with len(x) elements.
This the code :

```
import timeit

import numpy as np
from numba import jit, prange

def func_np (par,x):
    return(par[0]*np.exp(par[1]*x))

@jit('float64[:](float64[:], float64[:])', nopython=True, parallel=True)
def func_parallel(par,x):
    length=len(x)
    result = np.empty(length, dtype=np.float64)
    for i in prange(length):
        result[i] = par[0]*np.exp(par[1]*x[i])
    return result

x=np.array(np.arange(0,100,0.0001))
par=np.array([10,0.1])
print("numpy only")
%timeit func_np(par,x)
print("")
print("numba")
%timeit func_parallel(par,x)
```

The output is :

```
numpy only
28.1 ms ± 27.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

numba
2.05 ms ± 13.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

So, everything worked well. I have a large time decrease with numba optimization. (The machine where this code runs has 48 cores.).

After, I decided to use an array of a and b parameters (`par=np.array([[i*10,i*0.1] for i in range(10)]`), x is unchanged. 
This is the beginning of my problems. First, as the output is a 2D array of shape (10 ,len(x)) elements, it seems that I could not use `@jit` decorator but I must use `@guvectorize` decorator. I have written this code (very similar to the one above) that works :

```
import timeit

import numpy as np
from numba import guvectorize, prange

def func_np (par,x):
    return(par[:,0:1]*np.exp(par[:,1:2]*x))

@guvectorize([ 'float64[:,:], float64[:,:], float64[:]' ], '(m,n),(m,p),(n)', nopython=True, target='parallel')
def func_parallel(result,par,x):
    lenght=len(x)
    for i in prange(lenght):
        result[:,i] = (par[:,0:1]*np.exp(par[:,1:2]*x[i])).T
         
x=np.array(np.arange(0,100,0.0001))
par=np.array([[i*10,i*0.1] for i in range(10)])
print("numpy only")
%timeit func_np(par,x)
print("")
print("numba")
result = np.empty([par.shape[0],x.shape[0]], dtype=np.float64)
%timeit func_parallel(result, par,x);
```

But, the benchmarks are not good. The code with numba optimization is slower than the code written only with numpy functions.

```
numpy only
358 ms ± 307 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

numba
563 ms ± 2.82 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

As it is the first time I used numba, I suppose there is something that I have not understood. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

i don't exactly know what guvectorize does to slow you down (most likely creating extra unnecessary threads), but it's simple to make a better defined implementation.

consider the following implementation which is faster than numpy implementation.

```py
@jit('float64[:,:](float64[:,:], float64[:])', nopython=True,parallel=True)
def func_parallel(par, x):
    result = np.zeros((par.shape[0],len(x)),dtype=np.float64)
    lenght = len(x)
    for i in prange(lenght):
        for j in range(par.shape[0]):
            result[j, i] = par[j, 0] * np.exp(par[j, 1] * x[i])
    return result
```

it works x3 faster on my 2C/4T machine, so it should be much faster on yours.